# Add label to webform options in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, webforms

I'm trying to group the option values by categories, and I want to add a label for each category. For example:

```
group A
    Doctor: Doctor
group B
    Nurse: Nurse
    Student: Student
Others: Others
```

Can I do that without custom or alter function? My YAML:

```
Doctor: Doctor
Nurse: Nurse
Student: Student
Others: Others
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
Ex:

```
pets:
 - Cat
 - Dog
 - Goldfish
```